# Removing "Using temporary; Using filesort" from this MySQL select+join+group by

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I have the following query:

```
select 
    t.Chunk as LeftChunk,
    t.ChunkHash as LeftChunkHash,
    q.Chunk as RightChunk,
    q.ChunkHash as RightChunkHash,
    count(t.ChunkHash) as ChunkCount
from
    chunks as t
    join
    chunks as q
    on
        t.ID = q.ID
group by LeftChunkHash, RightChunkHash
```

And the following explain table:

```
id  select_type table   type    possible_keys   key key_len ref rows    Extra
1   SIMPLE  t   ALL IDIndex NULL    NULL    NULL    17796190    "Using temporary; Using filesort"
1   SIMPLE  q   ref IDIndex IDIndex 4   sotero.t.Id 12
```

note the "using temporary; using filesort".

When this query is run, I quickly run out of RAM (presumably b/c of the temp table), and then the HDD kicks in, and the query slows to a halt.

I thought it might be an index issue, so I started adding a few that sort of made sense:

```
Table   Non_unique  Key_name    Seq_in_index    Column_name Collation   Cardinality Sub_part    Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment Index_comment
chunks  0   PRIMARY 1   ChunkId A   17796190    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   ChunkHashIndex  1   ChunkHash   A   243783  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   IDIndex 1   Id  A   1483015 NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   ChunkIndex  1   Chunk   A   243783  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   ChunkTypeIndex  1   ChunkType   A   2   NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   chunkHashByChunkIDIndex 1   ChunkHash   A   243783  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   chunkHashByChunkIDIndex 2   ChunkId A   17796190    NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   chunkHashByChunkTypeIndex   1   ChunkHash   A   243783  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   chunkHashByChunkTypeIndex   2   ChunkType   A   261708  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   chunkHashByIDIndex  1   ChunkHash   A   243783  NULL    NULL        BTREE       
chunks  1   chunkHashByIDIndex  2   Id  A   17796190    NULL    NULL        BTREE
```

But still using the temporary table.

The db engine is MyISAM.

How can I get rid of the using temporary; using filesort in this query?

Just changing to InnoDB w/o explaining the underlying cause is not a particularly satisfying answer. Besides, if the solution is to just add the proper index, then that's much easier than migrating to another db engine.

I am new to relational databases. So I'm hoping that the solution is something obvious to the experts.

EDIT1:

ID is not the primary key. ChunkID is. There are approximately 40 ChunkIDs for each ID. So adding an additional ID to the table adds about 40 rows. Each unique chunk has a unique chunkHash associated with it.

EDIT2:

Here's the schema:

```
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
ChunkId int(11) NO  PRI NULL    
ChunkHash   int(11) NO  MUL NULL    
Id  int(11) NO  MUL NULL    
Chunk   varchar(255)    NO  MUL NULL    
ChunkType   varchar(255)    NO  MUL NULL
```

EDIT 3:

The end objective of the query is to create a table of word co-occurrences across documents. ChunkIDs are word instances. Each instance is a word that is associated with a particular document (ID). About 40 words present per document. About 1 million documents. So the resulting table of co-occurrences is highly compressed compared to the full cross-product temporary table that is (apparently) being created. That is, the full cross-product temp table is 1 mil * 40 * 40 = 1.6 billion rows. The compressed resulting table is estimated at about 40 million rows.

EDIT 4:

Adding postgresql tag to see if any postgresql users can get a better execution plan on that SQL implementation. If that's the case, I'll switch over.

Comment: What are the table definitions? Is ID a primary key on each table? If not, what sor of distribution of values are there?

Comment: If ChunkHash is guaranteed to be unique then isn't the count column always going to be 1?

Comment: If there are 40 records for each ID, then the cross product (join) will explode to 1600 joined records, which could add up quickly.  Is that the sort of join behavior you are looking for?

Comment: 1600 is fine for a temp table. But the query reaches 6GBs in 2 mins, so I think that it's creating a much larger cross product temp table.

Comment: If you have on average 40 rows for each ID, then your join is going to create 40 x 40  = 1600 rows in the result set for each ID.  That combinatorial explosion is probably what's swamping your server's RAM.  The server has to sort all this stuff to handle your GROUP BY. Unless you can make your join's ON-clause more restrictive, you may be stuck with this.   Can you explain what you're trying to accomplish?

Comment: The trouble is that you're having to do a group by over the whole result set, not just the 1600 combination. Does http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/4aecb/3 look like a decent set of small sample data?

Comment: @OllieJones That's right. And then the group by should collapse duplicates, generating a much smaller overall result set. I guess conceptually what I'd like to happen is to not have to generate all of the 1600row temp tables before the final collapsing is done. So iterate across leftChunkHash,rightChunkHash groupings, instead of iterating across IDs?

Comment: Your MySQL server is doing what you asked it to do. It's doing it correctly with the resources it has. It doesn't create multiple 1600-row temp tables, it creates one dirty great temp table and sorts it to group it. It seems you need a different algorithm to achieve your objective. I think SO folks would be able to help you cook up a better algorithm. But I, for one, can't figure out your objective from your query.

Comment: @Laurence That's it. That's the first time I've seen that tool. Very nice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I migrated from MySQL to PostgreSQL, and query execution time went from ~1.5 days to ~10 mins.

Here's the PostgreSQL query execution plan:

[image]

I am no longer using MySQL.

Answer (score 2):

Updated with a query that produces the same results. It won't be any faster though.

```
Create Index IX_ID On Chunks (ID);

Select
  LeftChunk,
  LeftChunkHash,
  RightChunk,
  RightChunkHash,
  Sum(ChunkCount)
From (
  Select 
    t.Chunk as LeftChunk,
    t.ChunkHash as LeftChunkHash,
    q.Chunk as RightChunk,
    q.ChunkHash as RightChunkHash,
    count(t.ChunkHash) as ChunkCount
  From
    chunks as t
      inner join
    chunks as q
      on t.ID = q.ID
  Group By
    t.ID,
    t.ChunkHash,
    q.ChunkHash 
  ) x
Group By
  LeftChunk,
  LeftChunkHash,
  RightChunk,
  RightChunkHash
```

Fiddle with example test data  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/ea1a5/2

Latest Fiddle, with the problem reformulated as words and documents: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5aef/12

With the problem reformulated as documents and words, how many documents do you have, how many words, and how many document words?

Also, using the documents and words analogy, would you say your query is "For all pairs of words that appear in a document together, how often do they appear together in any document. If word A appears `n` times in a document and word B `m` times in the same document, then this counts as `n * m` times in the total."

Comment: This did not change the planned execution path for my setup. Maybe I really do need to switch DB engines (to InnoDB?), or SQL implementations entirely (to postgresql?) Can you get a different planned execution path for the small dataset with your setup?

Comment: What if I somehow embed the group by in the join, and then do a count on the number of records returned for each unique product in the join?

Comment: That's right. Think of ID as document ID, chunk as a word in a document, and chunkhash as the integer hash for that word. So 'the' could appear twice in the same document.

Comment: I think what I'd like SQL to do is to iterate over the possible leftChunkHash,rightChunkHash combinations (constrained by that pesky ID term) and do a count for each iteration, instead of iterating over each ID first and then doing a huge collapse/count at the end. Which to me, I think means that chunkHash needs to be in a join somewhere.

Comment: Right; see how A,A is listed twice in your second query. And only once in the first. In a sense, each pairing could be a primary key in the result set. There has to be a way to take advantage of that, and tell SQL to iterate over each pairing, instead of building one giant table and collapsing at the end.

Comment: I can't think of a way yet, but I normalised the data a bit more like so:  http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/f5aef/12. Off to sleep on it.

Comment: Nice. Yeah, the real compression happens when duplicate LeftWord,RightWord's are collapsed across document ID, so I wouldn't think that grouping within first, and then collapsing after, would save much mem space.

Answer (score 2):

How about summarizing the table before the join?

The summary might be:

```
 select count(*) count,
        Chunk,
        ChunkHash
   from chunks
  group by Chunk, ChunkHash
```

Then the join would be:

```
Select r.Chunk as RightChunk,
       r.ChunkHash as RightChunkHash,
       l.Chunk as LeftChunk,
       l.ChunkHash as LeftChunkHash
       sum (l.Count) + sum(r.Count) as Count
  from (
        select count(*) count,
               Chunk,
               ChunkHash
          from chunks
      group by Chunk, ChunkHash
       ) l
  join (
        select count(*) count,
               Chunk,
               ChunkHash
          from chunks
      group by Chunk, ChunkHash
       ) r on l.Chunk = r.Chunk
 group by r.Chunk, r.ChunkHash, l.Chunk, l.ChunkHash
```

The thing I'm not sure about is what you're counting, exactly. So my SUM() + SUM() is a guess.  You might want SUM() * SUM().

Also, I'm assuming that two Chunk values are equal if and only if ChunkHash values are equal.

Comment: This misses the join on ID, but I think you might be on to something nonetheless.

Comment: The join on ID is the thing that's blowing out server RAM.

Comment: That may be the case, but this produces a completely different grouping: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/22eb0b/7